# Modifying state object directly re rendering the component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was going through ReactJS documentation. I came across following concept in State and lifecycle section which says

> Do Not Modify State Directly For example, this will not re-render a
>   component:

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

I tried to implement the same behavior and saw that the  component got re rendered

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            time : new Date(),
            note: "Time is-"
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimer(this.timerId);
    }
    render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.note}{this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
    }
    tick() {
        this.state.note = "Dude!! Time is";
        this.setState({
            time : new Date()
        })  
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The text got re rendered to "Dude Time is" from "Time is"

Can someone explain this? This behavior goes against what react documentation says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working because you are also doing the `setState` after `this.state.note = "Dude!! Time is"`. If you remove the `setState` call after this line, the example won't work.

Here is the link to the codesandbox. I've removed the `setState` call.

https://codesandbox.io/s/50r500j62p

Comment: So you mean setState will trigger re rendering irrespective of any property being modified inside setState method. I was expecting "note" not to be re rendered as its not being updated through setState

Comment: Yes, Exactly. When you do `setState` react will enqueue a state update and it will cause the rerender, even for the same value ;)

Comment: Understood the concept of setState. Thanks for the explanation